# How do i test my application for network perfomance while only having a single PC?

Tags: winforms, windows

Assume I have built high available and high reliable application. Now I need to test it for network performance. But I have only a single desktop computer at home. How do I test my application for network performance?

Is there an app that will create virtual clients and create a virtual network environment (but all clients are not humans except me) so I could create a network of 100 machines virtually from my single desktop??????

If there are apps like that, how many of them available for free?

My desktop runs on windows 8

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean for example like test if you have some concurrence problems trhowing a lot of calls to your service from different threads?

You can try, **Jmeter**. It´s free, and you can configure for example to run 10 tests, and run all the tests at the same time from 10 different threads.

Is a good ay to simulate x number of calls ;)

I am not sure, but I believe that with **SoapUI** you can do more or less the same too

Comment: yea something like that : ) I just I have one computer and I need to setup a network within but only from one computer, through that I have check data transmission from node1 to node2 and have the data received correctly and are there delays or drop outs...etc all this has to be done from one single machine in the network

Comment: Then try with one of this two. SoapUI or Jmeter. You will be able to do it ;)

Comment: will it set up the network of e.g. 20-30 clients? will I be able work with it like I do with an actual physical network?

Comment: also I forgot to mention my testing app was written in .net

Comment: mmm, you will be able to check if you have concurrence problems opening several connections at a time. Or like if for example, 100 other pc´s in a network call your method at the same time. SOmething like this ;) I think that you can do it whit this tools

Answer (score 0):

You could use Virtual Machines (for example [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)) and run them on your single machine.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to model a virtual network in a box then look to Shunra.  You can usually pick up used Shunra devices on EBAY for a fraction of their initial cost and their value for testing purposes.    You can model very accurately complex network infrastructures with their devices and then alter routing on your box to go out one IP address from a  Virtual machine, traverse the complex network of delays and route back to your service on the same box.

If you want something less than investing in hardware, then take a look at Charles Proxy.   It's a great piece of software that would allow you from a couple of hosts to look at the behavior across an impaired link with particular characteristics.   You can also alter some of the caching characteristics of the application in the proxy to see how this alters your perceived performance.

If you just want to model your data flows for the application then take a look at IxChariot (from Ixia Communications)  and pair it with Shunra.   You could crank up the number of dataflows and see what happens purely to the network response times independent of the performance of the application